# Save images from url strings

Tags: php, server

I've got a `.ashx` file with a bunch of urls (directing to a image) as blank text.

What I want to do is:

- Read the file
- Sort the images by url:
- *.../img/product/**004**/big/004-30.jpg*
- *.../img/product/**004**/big/004-31.jpg*
- ...
- *../img/product/**007**/big/007-21.jpg*
- Save the images on a remote server

So that they are in "seperate" folders.

What I got so far:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("http://versailles.edem.ua/imglist.ashx","r");
    $fileArray = array();
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $fileArray[] = $line;
    }

    //SORT THE ARRAYS BY NAME (See above)

    //DETECT IMAGES FROM THIS STRING-ARRAY

    //SAVE EACH IMAGE ON A REMOTE SERVER IN A SPECIFIC FOLDER (004, 007)
?>
```

---

```
// EDIT CODE
<?php
$file = fopen("http://versailles.edem.ua/imglist.ashx","r");
$fileArray = array();
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}

usort($fileArray, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
     return strcmp($elem1['title'], $elem2['title']);
});

print_r($fileArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**//SORT THE ARRAYS BY NAME (See above)**

You should use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)() (i'm assuming PHP 5.3+ here):

```
usort($your_array, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
     return strcmp($elem1['title'], $elem2['title']);
});
```

**//DETECT IMAGES FROM THIS STRING-ARRAY**

For each string in array, veirfy if it contains ".jpg" using [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
strrpos($foo, '.jpg', -4)
```

**//SAVE EACH IMAGE ON A REMOTE SERVER IN A SPECIFIC FOLDER (004, 007)**

Use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function:

```
copy('http://www.google.co.in/img/product/004/big/004-30.jpg', '/tmp-folder/004-30.jpeg');
```

Comment: At the moment every line of the `.ashx` file is a array. Is it possible to sort this arrays by a specific value of the array?

Comment: I get this error message `Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 9` - Check my updated answer.

Comment: You have to replace `title` with your element index

Comment: The index is changing. `http://versailles.edem.ua/img/product/004/big/004-30.jpg` - I want to sort this urls by the number after `/product/`

Comment: You can use `strpos` to get only this number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82088/discussion-between-samuel-and-nerdkowski).

Comment: Hey my friend. I need your help. [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82088/discussion-between-samuel-and-nerdkowski)

Comment: Hey, was on vacation :) ...let me know what's going http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82088/discussion-between-samuel-and-nerdkowski

Comment: Hey. :) You've got maybe one minute again? [CHAT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82088/discussion-between-samuel-and-nerdkowski)